# Server crashing - Error 106 and .dmp files

Tags: windows-server-2003, server-crashes, dump

A server is crashing with increasing frequency. Prior to crashing there are no events in the eventlog which indicate why it is crashing. There is no bluescreen and it does not respond to pings, show anything on the KVM, etc.

I have 2 questions.

1) I have configured the server to create dump files as we are not getting eventvwr information which indiciates why it crashes. Is there any *good* method to learn how to browse those and find issues quickly? It's not something I've worked with in the past.

2) Event 106 shows up with some frequency in the hour or so before rebooting. It is on Server 2003 (our last one...but it's an appliance and we're still waiting to get a way to virtualize it) and shows the source as WMIxWDM. The exact text is: "Machine Check Event reported is a corrected error" and shows as a warning.

Does anything think this error might be contributing to the crashing? Right now we've had 2 crashes in as many weeks, prior to this it was ~monthly and less awhile before that.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You know what would be helpful? Posting the details of Event ID 106. Also, is the server actually crashing/rebooting or is it simply hung up? Assuming it's a BSOD, have you disabled automatic restarts so that you can catch the BSOD information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're seeing correctable Machine Check Exceptions with some frequency, the most likely cause is hardware failure. You should take a look at your baseboard management logs (HP iLO, Dell DRAC, IBM Remote Supervisor, etc) or the hardware management software that came with your server (HP Insight, Dell OpenManage, etc) for any anomalies.

Comment: Unfortunately this is some whitebox hardware with no management control ports which I can find. We're going to order a new ram chip to swap out and see if that fixes things. Thanks for your help!